# When did a ninja ever get sucked up into a jet engine?

Tags: comics

I was reading my newly-purchased back issue of *The Tick* #3, which contains these panels:

[image: tick reading about ninjas]

What the hell is the Tick talking about?  A movie, I would assume, but I haven't been able to turn up which one by searching.

Comment: Immediately had to think of *Face Off*, but that was no Ninja...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The joke here is that the Tick, and everyone around him, frankly, is ***totally insane***.

He seems to have a peculiar blind spot for ninjas. Earlier in the same issue he states that ninjas are more scared of you than you are of them (No, Tick, that's *bears*) and then says that he thinks that they get sucked into jet engines (No, Tick, that's *geese*).

Oh, and then in the following issue he mistakes a row of ninjas for a hedge, *even as they're attacking him*.